# How do I add this code to what I already have in oder for this code to work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I would like to implement the second code into the first one in order for it to work as intended. I am unsure how to do this 
Current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !function(){
    var campaign_link = ""; // REPLACE WITH YOUR LINK
    var t;             
    try{
      for(t=0;10>t;++t)history.pushState({},"","#");
      onpopstate=function(t){t.state&&location.replace(campaign_link + window.location.search.substring(1))}}
    catch(o){}
  }();
</script>
```

the code I would like to add to existing code;

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    window.location.href = location.href;
});
```

Comment: are you just looking to store the current window.location to be used in your function?

Comment: the first code works fine in all browsers except chrome ios the second code is way to make it work in ios chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this function to your current script like so. However you may want to store the loction.href in a var as opposed to window.location

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function(){
    var campaign_link = ""; // REPLACE WITH YOUR LINK
    var t;             
    try{
      for(t=0;10>t;++t)history.pushState({},"","#");
      onpopstate=function(t){t.state&&location.replace(campaign_link + window.location.search.substring(1))}}
    catch(o){}
  }();

  window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    window.location.href = location.href;
  });

</script>
```

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: var url = window.location.href  ?

Comment: yep `window.location.href` returns a string https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: and then i replace?

Comment: var url = window.location.href;
       url =  "";
    window.location.href = url;

Comment: Hmm but basically the script i have right now does not work in chrome ios and I am trying to figure out who i can make it work  in chrom ios.

Comment: use `location.href` instead of `window.location.href`this will allow both ios and chrome to work

Comment: i change url = 'what ever my link is";
that what it replaces the current url to the desired url
or do i have to implement something else

Comment: that'll do it, or just use `location.href` where required

Comment: i did that it and it works on all other browser but still not on ios chrome
can you edit the code in they way youd do it? may be im mising something